# In Koa, can I access Koa-router context at middleware invocation?

Tags: koa, koa-router

I want to pass a parameter into middleware

```
router.get(
  '/:id',
  myMiddlware({projectid : ctx.request.query.projectid } ),
  async (ctx) => {...}
)
```

I need to get the value of 'projectid' in the middleware declaration but of course, ctx from Koa-router isn't created yet (I think).

My middleware is defined as :

```
module.exports.myMiddleware = (fromSource) => async (ctx, next) => {...
```

I know I'm making a logical mistake somewhere!